# 400 bad request on post when using express json

Tags: node.js, shopify-api

I use shopify api to recieve webhooks and all works. But when I use this two lines then I get 400 bad request.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
```

When I remove this it works but when I add this it wont work. Why ? I need this two lines above

POST webhook

```
// Process webhooks
app.post('/webhooks', express.text({type: '*/*'}), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Note: the express.text() given above is an Express middleware that will read
    // in the body as a string, and make it available at req.body, for this path only.
    const d = await shopify.webhooks.process({
      rawBody: req.body, // is a string
      rawRequest: req,
      rawResponse: res,
    });

    console.log('PROCESS');
  } catch (e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want `rawBody` to be string?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know shopify webhooks don't get sent as strings but get sent as json, try:

```
app.post('/webhooks', express.json(), async (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: its not working. https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/packages/shopify-api/docs/guides/webhooks.md#note-regarding-use-of-body-parsers